# Show $n^{-p}*S_{n} \to 0$ in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

Suppose we have a sequence of i.i.d random variables $\{X_{n}\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^{2} < \infty$. We want to show that $n^{-p}S_{n} \to 0$ in probability when $p>\frac{1}{2}$.

Here's my attempt

> Showing $n^{-p}S_{n} \to 0$ in probability is equivalent to showing $$\Bbb P\left(\left|\frac{S_{n}}{n^{p}}\right|\leq \epsilon\right) \to 1 $$
>
> Rearrange the expression in the bracket we finally get
>   $$\Bbb P\left(\left|\frac{S_{n}}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}\right| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\sigma}n^{p-\frac{1}{2}}\right).$$
>
> By central limit theorem, we know $\frac{S_{n}}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \to N(0,1)$ in distribution. But my question is that can we directly write the expression above as $$2\Phi \left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sigma}n^{p-\frac{1}{2}}\right)-1$$ and argue that as $n \to \infty$, we get $$\Bbb P\left(\left|\frac{S_{n}}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}\right| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\sigma}n^{p-\frac{1}{2}}\right) \to 1$$
>
> I don't know if central limit theorem is still valid when the expression in the bracket changes, Could someone help me with it? if not, how to prove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The central limit theorem gives that for all fixed point $t$, 
$$\tag{*}
\mathbb P\left(\left\lvert \frac{S_n}{\sigma\sqrt n}\right\rvert\leqslant t\right)\to 
\mathbb P(\lvert N\vert\leqslant t)
$$
where $N$ has a standard normal distribution.

Actually, one can show that the convergence is also uniform on $\mathbb R$ because the limiting distribution function is continuous.

We can also conclude without using the uniform convergence: fix $R\gt 0$; for $n$ 
large enough, $\epsilon n^{p-1/2}\geqslant R$ hence 
$$
\mathbb P\left(\left\lvert \frac{S_n}{\sigma\sqrt n}\right\rvert\leqslant \epsilon n^{p-1/2} \right)\geqslant\mathbb P\left(\left\lvert \frac{S_n}{\sigma\sqrt n}\right\rvert\leqslant R \right).
$$
Taking the $\liminf_{n\to+\infty}$ and using (*) with $t=R$ gives 
$$
\liminf_{n\to+\infty}\mathbb P\left(\left\lvert \frac{S_n}{\sigma\sqrt n}\right\rvert\leqslant \epsilon n^{p-1/2} \right)\geqslant\mathbb P\left(\left\lvert N\right\rvert\leqslant R \right).
$$
Now, since $R$ the previous inequality is valid for all $R$, we derive that 
$$
\liminf_{n\to+\infty}\mathbb P\left(\left\lvert \frac{S_n}{\sigma\sqrt n}\right\rvert\leqslant \epsilon n^{p-1/2} \right)\geqslant1.$$

Answer (score 0):

We can write $\frac{1}{n^p}S_n=\frac{1}{n^{p-1/2}}\frac{{S_n}}{\sqrt{n}}$

$\frac{{S_n}}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution to $N(0,\sigma^2),$ and $\frac{1}{n^{p-1/2}}$ converges in distribution to $0$ then $\frac{1}{n^p}S_n$ converges in distribution to $0$ which means convergence in probability to $0$.